# Why are actor-critic neural networks created in this way?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Deep Deterministic Policy Gradients ([DDPG](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02971)) and stable Baseline Code is presented [here](https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/blob/master/stable_baselines/ddpg/ddpg.py).

The actor-critic networks are created as follows:

```
normalized_obs = tf.clip_by_value(normalize(self.policy_tf.processed_obs, self.obs_rms),
                                                   self.observation_range[0], self.observation_range[1])

# Inputs.
self.actions = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,) + self.action_space.shape, name='actions')


# Create networks and core TF parts that are shared across setup parts.
with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=False):
    self.actor_tf = self.policy_tf.make_actor(normalized_obs)
    self.normalized_critic_tf = self.policy_tf.make_critic(normalized_obs, self.actions)
    self.normalized_critic_with_actor_tf = self.policy_tf.make_critic(normalized_obs,
                                                                      self.actor_tf,
                                                                      reuse=True)
```

The following image gives a general depiction of actor-critic networks.

After each action taken by the poliucy/actor, the critic evaluates the new state to determine if things have gotten better or worse. It also receives the reward achieved from the set of actions taken in the environment.

[image]

I understand that:

- `actor_tf` takes as inputs the normalised observations and goals.

What I don't understand:

1. `critic_tf` takes as input the normalised observations and goals as well as the **set of actions**.
2. why we are passing `self.actor_tf` to create `self.normalized_critic_with_actor_tf`.

My questions therefore are:

1. What does `self.normalized_critic_with_actor_tf` represent in the diagram above and why is it used?
2. Why are actions being passed to the critic input, instead of the reward as depicted in the diagram above? As defined by OpenAI docs, the observation does not contain the reward.